# Chrome extension that changes the wallpaper of a new tab - NOT in Chrome OS

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extensions, but I understand the basics of how to set them up. However, this one issue is stumping me. I basically just want to create an extension that fetches an image from an API and then sets it to be the wallpaper of Chrome's new tab. I want this to happen in the default chrome://newtab page.

The only thing I've been able to find is the chrome.wallpaper API, but that only works on Chrome OS. Is there any way to do what it does but on a different OS? Or is the only solution here to create a completely separate HTML page that overrides the default one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The default newtab cannot be customized. You can only write your own version.